# Flutter: ListView display issue

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Hello having issue with my listview populating data when a search is done.

```
Future<void> _fetchClientProducts(client, product) async {
String url;
url = "http://192.168.25.48/lomacs/xml/integration?query=getproducts&client=" + client + "&product_id=" + product;
    try {
      var response = await http.get(url);
      var xmlDocument = xml.XmlDocument.parse(response.body);
      for (var xmlElement in xmlDocument.findAllElements('product')) {
        products.add(
          Product(
            productId: xmlElement.findElements('product_id').single.text,
            scanId: xmlElement.findElements('scan_id').single.text,
            productTitle: xmlElement.findElements('prod_title').single.text,
            qtyAvailable: xmlElement.findElements('qty_availability').single.text,
            productImage: xmlElement.findElements('product_image').single.text,
          ),
        );
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

I have attached an image of the first attempt to search but i click enter it does query my future api call but the listview below it does not populate until i click enter again as seen in screenhot 2.

[screenshot #1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWp1Q.png)

[screenshot #2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX9b6.png)

Any help would be great thanks.

Edit:
UI Code

```
new ExpansionTile(
                    title: new Text("Items"),
                    children: <Widget>[
                      TextField(
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                              hintText: "Search for Product"),
                          onSubmitted: (String str) {
                            if (str.length == 0) {
                              ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                                SnackBar(
                                  content: Text(
                                      'you must enter a product to search'),
                                ),
                              );
                              return;
                            }
                            print("search for product: " + str);
                            _fetchClientProducts('CLIENTCODE', str);
                            setState(() {

                            });
                          }),
                      Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            width: double.infinity,
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 0),
                            child: ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemCount: products.length,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                return _buildListItemProduct(
                                    products[index], context);
                              },
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
```

```
_buildListItemProduct(Product news, BuildContext context) {
  return Card(
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 15, top: 0, left: 10),
            //decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.grey),
            child: news.productImage == null || news.productImage.isEmpty
                ? SizedBox(height: 1)
                : Image.network(
                    news.productImage,
                    fit: BoxFit.fitWidth),
          ),
          Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5, left: 15, bottom: 5, right: 5),
              child: Text(
                  "Product ID: " +
                      news.productId +
                      "\nScan ID: " +
                      news.scanId +
                      "\nTitle: " +
                      news.productTitle +
                      "\nAvailable Qty: " +
                      news.qtyAvailable,
                  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16))),
          Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              TouchSpin(
                min: 0,
                max: 9999999999,
                step: 1,
                value: 0,
                //displayFormat:NumberFormat.currency(locale: 'en_US', symbol: '\$'),
                textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
                iconSize: 24.0,
                addIcon: Icon(Icons.add_circle_outline),
                subtractIcon: Icon(Icons.remove_circle_outline),
                iconActiveColor: Colors.black,
                iconDisabledColor: Colors.grey,
                //iconPadding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
                onChanged: (val) {
                  if (val > 0) {
                    // check available qty
                    if (val > int.parse(news.qtyAvailable)) {
                      print(
                          "you have order more than the available qty this order will go on backhold if submitted.");
                    }

                    var message;
                    message = cart.addToCart(
                        productId: news.productId, unitPrice: 0, quantity: val);
                    //print(message);
                  }
                },
              ),
            ],
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          ),
          //Divider(height: 20,color: Colors.grey,),
        ],
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      ),
    ),
    margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, left: 10, right: 10),
  );
}
```

Comment: Can you add your UI code?

Comment: @Stijn2210 done

Comment: the problem is is that your fetch method is a Future and you're not awaiting it. Add the async keyword after onsubmitted so `onSubmitted() async` and then add the await keyword before _fetch. like `await _fetchproduct`

Comment: @Stijn2210 wow thanks thats all it was.